# fs::dir_ls() Not Handling Non-ASCII Characters in Filenames Correctly

Tags: r

I am encountering an issue with the `fs::dir_ls()` function in R on Windows, where it's not handling non-ASCII characters in filenames correctly. This issue started occurring after some unknown changes were made to the machine.

#### Problem Description

- **Environment**: R version 3.6.2 on Windows.
- **Issue**: Previously, `fs::dir_ls(my_dir)` would locate files and display their names correctly, even with characters like ü. However, now it prints weird characters in place of ü and `fs::file_exists(x)` returns `FALSE` for these files.

#### What I've Tried

- I attempted to change the locale settings in R with `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")`, but it did not resolve the issue and resulted in a warning.
- The issue cannot be reproduced on another machine with the same R version.

#### Additional Information

- `Sys.getlocale()` returns:
  `"LC_COLLATE=Greek_Greece.1253;LC_CTYPE=Greek_Greece.1253;LC_MONETARY=Greek_Greece.1253;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Greek_Greece.1253"`
- `l10n_info()` returns:

`$MBCS: FALSE  $UTF-8: FALSE $Latin-1: FALSE $codepage: 1253`

- `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")` returns:

`[1] "" Warning message: In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8") : OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored`

I do not know how to reproduce this issue in another machine, and I do not know how to fix the existing one. Any insights or suggestions on how to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What Windows version are you using? Is there a reason you are using such an old version of R?

Comment: I am on Windows 10 enterprise. I am using on R 3.6.2 because library excel.link, which I have used a lot, is not working on R 4.0.0+. I concede that upgrading to R 4.3.2 seems to solve this problem, but is creating another one. I will consider this approach, but I'd like to know how I can solve the encoding issue in the old version.

Comment: Comparing the two R versions, it looks like the new one is automatically setting locale to UTF-8, while the older one seems unable to do so. In R 4.3.2 `l10n_info()['UTF-8']` is `TRUE` and ` Sys.getlocale()` returns UTF-8 in all fields. I do not understand why `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")` does not work in the older version, because I am sure the problem didn't originally exist.